# How to get html tag auto completion?

Tags: indentation, autocompletion, filetype-html

I can't seem to figure out how to implement auto tag completion for html.

Is there a plug-in or something else you guys use that works? Is there just one thing I can download that will handle indentation, html syntax and other bare bones stuff as well?

Comment: With omni-completion set to syntax#complete, html tags complete fairly well. Surround.vim is good working with tags. Afaik the default indent for html filetypes is good enough. Can you be a little more specific with your question?